# Shapes bounded only by lines

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, terminology

What is a term for the set of geometric shapes in the plane, that are bounded by one or more continuous closed curves?

This set contains simply-connected polygons and circles but also polygons with holes. It doesn't include polygons with a singular point added or missing.

MOTIVATION: I am looking for a set, as large as possible, on which the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) defines a metric, i.e., the symmetric difference of two different shapes always has positive area. This holds (I think) for the set of closed simply-connected 2-dimensional shapes, but I am trying to expand it further, to shapes that may have holes.   The set of all closed connected shapes is too inclusive as it includes, for example, both the unit disc $D$ and $D\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, and the difference between them has area 0.

Comment: Hmm. 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: It doesn't hold for closed, simply-connected shapes. For instance, the lines from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ and from $(0,0)$ to $(2,0)$ are both closed and simply connected, but their symmetric difference has zero area.

Comment: @TonyK what about closed 2-dimensional simply-connected shapes?

Comment: What's a 2-dimensional shape? Please define it for me! It had better not have any 1-dimensional lines radiating from it. (And why does it have to be simply connected?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term would probably be 2-dim sub-manifold, but, given your motivation, I don't see why you need to limit yourself to those. The Lebesgue measure of the symmetric difference of measurable sets defines a metric (where sets which differ by a set of measure $0$ are considers identical).

You can, of course, limit your [metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) to "nicer" sets (e.g., open sets) but your metric space will not be [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space):
Consider a [Sierpinski carpet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet) $S$ (compact, empty interior) of non-zero measure (e.g. the [Wallis Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet#Wallis_sieve)). One can easily construct a sequence of nested open sets $A_n\subset A_m$ for $n>m$ so that $\cap A_n=S$, so $\lim_n \lambda(A_n\Delta S)=0$ but there is no open set $A$ such that $\lambda(A\Delta S)=0$.

Comment: A line and the empty set will be considered identical then...?

Comment: Yes, a line, a point, an empty set, the set of points with rational coordinates are all identical.

Comment: But that's exactly what the OP didn't want, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, I want a set in which different shapes are not considered identical...

Comment: Then your metric space will not be complete.

Comment: @sds: Why is that?

Comment: @TonyK: see edit.

Comment: In the metric space consisting of the open sets of finite measure under the symmetric difference metric, the limit of your $A_n$ is the empty set, isn't it?

Comment: @TonyK: sorry, you are right, I replaced my example. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: Why can't $A$ just be the interior of $S$?

Comment: Because $S$ has empty interior.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I removed my downvote :-)

Comment: Interesting. So the set of all open sets is not closed under the Symmetric Distance metric. The same example, I think, shows that my suggested set - all regions bounded by a finite number of curves - is not closed under the same metric. But why did you say that this will be true for *any* set in which different shapes are not considered identical?

Answer (score 1):

How about the set of all measurable sets with finite measure, that are equal to the closure of their interiors? I think that works.

Comment: This indeed rules out 2-dimensional shapes plus or minus a set of points and lines. But how can I prove that there are no other problematic cases?

Comment: The use of term measurable here is a bit unnecessary. All closed sets already are.

Comment: @TonyK I think you are right, and here is my proof: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1099461/29780