# How to make the Symmetric Distance a metric?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

I am trying to construct a family $S$ of measureable subsets or $R^2$, on which the symmetric difference, defined as: $SD(A,B) = Area(A\setminus B \cup B \setminus A)$, is a metric, i.e., different elements of $S$ have a symmetric difference with positive area, and $S$ is complete under that metric.

Consider first the family of open discs centered at the origin. Here $SD$ is obviously a metric, since different discs have different radii and $SD(A,B)=\pi|r_A^2-r_B^2|>0$. To make $S$ complete under this metric, we have to add the empty set (the limit when the $r\to 0$) and the entire plane $R^2$ (the limit when $r\to \infty$).

$SD$ remains a metric when we add all open discs, since the symmetric difference of discs with a different center also has positive area.

From similar considerations, it seems obvious that I can also add to $S$ all open triangles, quadrangles or polygons with the number of sides bounded by a constant (although I don't have a formal proof for that).

Initially I thought that I can also add to $S$ all open polygons and even all simply-connected open shapes, but now I think that this will make $S$ incomplete. The example I found for this is based on an [answer by Joonas Ilmavirta](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/909558/29780) and [an answer by sds](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/847192/29780):

Let $E_n$ be the interior of $n$-th step in the construction of a [Smith–Volterra–Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) in $(0,1)$. Define the following sequence of sets:

$$F_n=(0,1)\times(0,0.5) \cup E_n\times(0,1)$$

$F_n$ is a comb-shaped rectilinear polygon similar to the following:

[image]

with the number of dents growing as $n$ grows. Moreover, it is open and simply-connected. But, the limit of $F_n$ when $n\to\infty$ is not open and not a polygon. The area of the limit is $0.5 + 0.5\cdot 0.5=0.75$ but the 'closest' open set is $(0,1)\times(0,0.5)$ which has area 0.5.

So, my question is now: what subset of the open simply-connected shapes can I add to $S$, such that $SD$ remains a metric on $S$ and $S$ remains complete in that metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I think I found an answer:

**SD is a metric on the set of all regular closed sets**.

(A regular closed set is a set $X$ equal to the closure of its interior: $X=Cl[Int[X]]$).

Proof:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two regular closed sets such that $Area[X\setminus Y]=Area[Y\setminus X]=0$. We prove that $X=Y$.

$X\setminus Y = X\cap Y^C$ (where $Y^C$ is the complement of $Y$).

$X\cap Y^C \supseteq Int[X]\cap Y^C$

So $Area[Int[X]\cap Y^C]=0$

These two sets are both open so their intersection is open.

The only open set with an area of 0 is the empty set (because any non-empty open set contains a ball with a positive measure). Hence:

$Int[X]\cap Y^C=\emptyset$

$Int[X]\subseteq Y$

Take the Int of both sides:

$Int[X]\subseteq Int[Y]$

Similarly:

$Int[Y]\subseteq Int[X]$

Hence:

$Int[Y] = Int[X]$

Take the Cl of both sides and use the fact that they are regular closed:

$Y = X$

QED.

---

CREDITS:

[Shapes bounded only by lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847081/shapes-bounded-only-by-lines) (TonyK)

[When does intersection of measure 0 implies interior-disjointness?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872058/when-does-intersection-of-measure-0-implies-interior-disjointness) (PhoemueX and dafinguzman)

[Area of set-difference of special sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099185/area-of-set-difference-of-special-sets) (Henno Brandsma)

Answer (score 2):

1) No standard name.

2) You speak of the symmetric distance but you write $A\backslash B \cup B\backslash A$ which is the symmetric difference. It is not a metric and does not turn $S$ into a metric space.

3) Let $A$ and $B$ be any two distinct straight line segments. Their symmetric difference has $0$ area.

4) Is  $S$ complete? well, you'll have to first turn it into a metric space before you can ask this question.

Comment: Yes, I meant symmetric difference, fixed. What if I replace "closed" with "open" in the definition of *S* - does this make the symmetric distance a metric?

Comment: nope, it does not. To be a metric you need to assign a non-negative real number to any two elements. The symmetric difference is a set, not a number.

Comment: I use the area of the symmetric difference. I edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: How do you know the symmetric difference has any area at all? you need measurable sets to make this work so you need to refine your definition of $S$.

Comment: About (1): I once read the term "topological disc". Is it the correct term to describe the shapes in $S$ (except $\phi$ and $R^2$)? And is it clear that topological discs are measureable?

Comment: Your question is starting to get a bit chaotic, you may wish to spend some time thinking about what you want to do. In any case, if you take your sets to be closed then they are measurable but the area of the symmetric difference will not give you a metric. you may wish to read about the Hausdorff metric.

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote the question to better explain my motivation, I hope it is clearer now.